# Make a <a><div></div></a> responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 `<div>`'s in a row. The first two are wrapped around with a `<a>`-link. These are not responsive anymore. I try to do this with plain html and css. How can I make them responsive like the last one? This is my code:

(here is a codepen.io link to my problem: https://codepen.io/NiklasG/pen/oNoPVNL)

HTML:

```
<main>
  <div id= container>
    <a><div class="tile"></div></a>
    <a><div class="tile"></div></a>
    <div class="tile"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
main{
  padding: 30px;
}

#container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tile{
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border-style: dashed;
}
```

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: StackOverflow is not a "we'll do your work for you for free" site.
Show your effort, instead of asking for a ready solution. Show specific errors you need help with and example output that you expect.

Comment: Also, `<a><div></div></a>` is not valid HTML, you should not do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand from your question you want `a` to fill the whole `div`. As mentioned by Ron. `<a><div></div></a>` not valid HTML `a` should be inside of `div`

1-) First put `a` inside of `div`

```
<main>
  <div id= container>
    <div class="tile"><a></a></div>
    <div class="tile"><a></a></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

2-) Instead of using  px use percentages

```
.tile{
  width: 33%;
  height: 100px;
  border-style: dashed;
}
```

3-) then add this CSS to make `a` to fill the content.

```
a{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

4-) Use media queries to make it responsive

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .tile{
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
  }
  #container{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

This is the code pen link you can look https://codepen.io/kaanatesel/pen/JjOazWK

Answer (score 0):

Alternative, you can use **grid layout** to create 3 columns responsive on your `#container`.

I have change your class `title` for `title__container`

**Possible example:**

```css
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

main {
  padding: 30px;
}


/* You can better use grid */

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  /*optional*/
  /*gap: 1rem;*/
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  height: 100px;
}

#container .title__container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  border-style: dashed;
  /* you can use flex here if you want */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id=container>
    <a class='title__container' href='#'>
      <h2>Title 1</h2>
    </a>
    <a class='title__container' href='#'>
      <h2>Title 2</h2>
    </a>
    <div class="title__container">
      <h2>Title 3</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```